# doordash api and jwt issues

Tags: node.js, jwt

So I am just trying to follow the Doordash documentation to experiment with adding their service to a website or app, but for some reason I am running into this error that nobody else has seemed to have had in the past, and I can find no mention or help of it otherwise.

I continue to get "DoorDashAuthorizationError: The [exp] is in the past; the JWT is expired"
regardless of the fact that I am generating new jwt with each refresh. I have followed the guide step for step several times, or even trying other approached and still always comes back to this error.

JWT generation:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const accessKey = {
    "developer_id": "DEV",
    "key_id": "KEY",
    "signing_secret": "SECRET"
}

const data = {
    aud: 'doordash',
    iss: accessKey.developer_id,
    kid: accessKey.key_id,
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 60),
    iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
}

const headers = { algorithm: 'HS256', header: { 'dd-ver': 'DD-JWT-V1' } }  

const token = jwt.sign(
    data,
    Buffer.from(accessKey.signing_secret, 'base64'),   
    headers,
)

console.log(token)
```

creating initial delivery:

```
const DoorDashClient = require('@doordash/sdk')

const client = new DoorDashClient.DoorDashClient({
    developer_id: "DEV",
    key_id: "KEY",
    signing_secret: "SECRET"
  })

const response = client
  .createDelivery({
    external_delivery_id: 'D-12345',
    pickup_address: '1000 4th Ave, Seattle, WA, 98104',
    pickup_phone_number: '+1(650)5555555',
    dropoff_address: '1201 3rd Ave, Seattle, WA, 98101',
    dropoff_phone_number: '+1(650)5555555',
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

so with just the JWT generation, the server logs a new token each time with no issue, when I try to create an order, I get a new key, along with the error.

any insight would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue with the latest versions of DoorDash SDK. I had similar issues with 0.6.0^.

Moving to 0.4.6 has resolved this issue for me.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@doordash/sdk/v/0.4.6